# How to solve cross domain accessing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am working on a angularjs project which need to retrieve data from cross domain site(using $http to get). And it hit the problem "XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxxx . Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed". Anybody has idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that this policy is a feature intended to improve security, but if you know what you are doing see

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- [AngularJS : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665056/angularjs-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-readi)