# How authentication in a mobile app using JHipster Project?

Tags: java, spring-security, cors, jhipster

I created a JHipster project and created a mobile app, using ionic generator. I have configured my project to enable cross origin HTTP requests.

Running JHipster in dev mod, i try to make login in ionic app with this POST:

> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1445250957240 403
>   (Forbidden) XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1445250957240. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

What i need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665056/angularjs-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-readi

Comment: that information didn't help me

Comment: did you try to add your index.php the line <? php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>

Comment: I added that pair key/value header and the request type has changed to "OPTIONS" but nothing happens after that..

Comment: you have two servers on 8080 and 8100, you have to merge your data to 8100 or verify the configuration of apache for 8080

Comment: but i will always make request from diferent domains.. i dont have to merge to same domain

Comment: can you add some details about your server configuration in port 8100 ?

Comment: try to configure as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin , *` header to make an ajax call from another domain or port.

Comment: i changed the authentication type from HttpSession to Token authencation and solves my problem