# get the html content from url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to read the html content from given url, but it shows same origin error(I know about this error). So I have tried different method. Open a new window and open the website to that window and read the content from that window, but not work please help me.

**Note:** This is for my cordova application!

I tried like below

```
var myWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','','width=200,height=100');
//myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
alert(myWindow.innerHTML);
myWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: I would try and use a Cordova API

Comment: @alex Can you tell any cordova plugin name for this.

Comment: If you want to get content from url, i think you should use ajax $.get(...);

Comment: @IlyasMimouni it shown same origin error, like google...

Comment: @AsithRaj: you have to configure the server by adding some code php, take a look on the anwser here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665056/angularjs-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-readi

Answer (score 5):

```
$.get( "http://www.google.com/", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);     
});
```

With help of jQuery, you can get html content of specified URL. Replace your desired URL with `"http://www.google.com/"`. It won't give error in real device or Emulator. But if you will check in Browser then it will give error of CORS.

Regards

Comment: I tried in browser console window, over stackoverflow but it show "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error

Comment: Yes it will always give CORS error so you can not test in browsers try in real device.

Comment: @AsithRaj: just for information, there is a way to simulate in chrome browser, by activating some fonctions here : "chrome://flags/". but this part is very advanced in fonctionalities. so you shouldn't activate or disactivate a function only if you now what you are doing. :)

Comment: Yes i wouldn't recommend that too.